# Docker Container environment configuration?

Tags: asp.net, docker

I am currently trying to build a project with Docker for containerization. My Dockerfile is following the template for SPA ReactJS with ASP.NET:

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

#ENV PATH = "app/node-modules/bin:$PATH"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SaucedSampleWeb/SaucedSampleWeb.csproj", "SaucedSampleWeb/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SaucedSampleWeb/SaucedSampleWeb.csproj"
COPY . .

WORKDIR "/src/SampleWeb"
RUN dotnet build "SampleWeb.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SampleWeb.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.dll"]
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SampleWeb.dll"]
```

The image is build successfully, however there is the error occured when debugging, in which the path directory for npm command somehow is being referenced from the local machine's environment as well:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/npm' with working directory '/app/bin/Debug/net7.0/C:\Users\user\source\github\SampleWeb\ClientApp\'. No such file or directory
```

I thought that I need to declare PATH environment inside the Dockerfile, however it doesn't work so far. How can I fix this issue?

What I found in my container's details is as below, which I assume to be responsible to how the SPA Proxy is reference the directory pathway:

```
{
  "Id": "aa22c60670b0f1b5e100fd49292b07ecfb77f9c6d40e1794179b7b7c6d1074a7",
  "Created": "2023-07-03T04:00:48.562276392Z",
  "Path": "tail",
  "Args": [
    "-f",
    "/dev/null"
  ],
  
  ....

  
  "Mounts": [
    {
      "Type": "bind",
      "Source": "C:\\Users\\user\\source\\github\\SampleWeb",
      "Destination": "/app",
      "Mode": "",
      "RW": true,
      "Propagation": "rprivate"
    },
    {
      "Type": "bind",
      "Source": "/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/Users/user/source/github",
      "Destination": "/src",
      "Mode": "",
      "RW": true,
      "Propagation": "rprivate"
    },
    {
      "Type": "bind",
      "Source": "C:\\Users\\user\\.nuget\\packages\\",
      "Destination": "/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages",
      "Mode": "",
      "RW": true,
      "Propagation": "rprivate"
    },

    ...

    "Tty": true,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Env": [
      "ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS=true",
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development",
      "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80",
      "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=7203",
      "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1",
      "NUGET_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages",
      "NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages",
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
      "DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true",
      "DOTNET_VERSION=7.0.8",
      "ASPNET_VERSION=7.0.8"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "-f",
      "/dev/null"
    ],
    ...
    }
  }
}
```